# Qt Designer - Print screen of QMainWindow (preview mode) which has QScrollArea

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer, printscreen

As the title says i want to make some images in QtDesigner.

I used QMainWindow with QMenu, QToolBar, QScrollArea and QStatusBar.

I want the quality to be as best as possible.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Fault Print screen attached:

[image]

The problem is with the QScrollArea.

**Edit:** There is no problem if i use `pyuic5` command first to compile the .ui files to .py files

Comment: The question is unclear. First you say that you want to "print screen", then that you "make some images in QtDesigner”. Can you clarify?

Comment: Just print screen that produces images...

Comment: Sorry, but that comment is even more cryptic than the question. Try to *explain clearly* what you want to do.

Comment: @musicamante print screen attached.

Comment: "The problem is with the QScrollArea." **What** problem? Describe the issue and explain what is the expected behavior, because, as already said, it's completely unclear what you're referring to.